# Discrete Luenberger observer for the three phase induction motor

Tags: simulation, control, induction-motor

I have continuous time version of the Luenberger observer for the three phase induction motor in following form:

$$
\dot{\hat{\mathbf{x}}} = \mathbf{A}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{x}} + \mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{L}\cdot\left(\mathbf{y} - \hat{\mathbf{y}}\right) \\
\hat{\mathbf{y}} = \mathbf{C}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{x}} 
$$

$$
\mathbf{A}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{R_S + R_R}{L_L} & 0 & \frac{R_R}{L_M\cdot L_L} & \frac{1}{L_L}\cdot\omega_m \\
0 & -\frac{R_S + R_R}{L_L} & -\frac{1}{L_L}\cdot\omega_m & \frac{R_R}{L_M\cdot L_L} \\
R_R & 0 & -\frac{R_R}{L_M} & -\omega_m \\
0 & R_R & \omega_m & -\frac{R_R}{L_M}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\mathbf{B}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{L_L} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{L_L} \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\mathbf{L}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
l_1 & -l_2 \\
l_2 & l_1 \\
l_3 & -l_4 \\
l_4 & l_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
(K-1)\cdot\left(\frac{R_S+R_R}{L_L} + \frac{R_R}{L_M}\right) & (K-1)\cdot\omega_m \\
-(K-1)\cdot\omega_m & (K-1)\cdot\left(\frac{R_S+R_R}{L_L} + \frac{R_R}{L_M}\right) \\
(K^2-1)\cdot R_S - (K-1)\cdot\left(R_S + R_R + \frac{R_R\cdot L_L}{L_M}\right) & -(K-1)\cdot L_L\cdot\omega_m \\
(K-1)\cdot L_L\cdot\omega_m  & (K^2-1)\cdot R_S - (K-1)\cdot\left(R_S + R_R + \frac{R_R\cdot L_L}{L_M}\right)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

\$R_S = 0.294\,(\Omega)\$, \$R_R = 0.151\,(\Omega)\$, \$L_L = 0.0021\,(\mathrm{H})\$, \$L_M = 0.0395\, (\mathrm{H})\$, \$K = 2\,(-)\$

$$
\mathbf{x}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
i_{s\alpha} \\
i_{s\beta} \\
\psi_{r\alpha} \\
\psi_{r\beta}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\mathbf{y}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
i_{s\alpha} \\
i_{s\beta}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\mathbf{u}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
u_{s\alpha} \\
u_{s\beta}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I am going to implement this observer in a software so I need to transform it into the discrete time version. I have decided to use the forward rectangular rule (according to the *Digital Control of Dynamic Systems*) for this transformation. Based on that the matrices of the continuous version of the Luenberger observer transform into their discrete equivalents according to following formulas

$$
\mathbf{A}_d \simeq \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{A}\cdot T
$$
$$
\mathbf{B}_d \simeq \mathbf{B}\cdot T
$$
$$
\mathbf{C}_d = \mathbf{C}
$$
$$
\mathbf{L}_{pd} = \mathbf{L}\cdot T,
$$

where \$T\$ is the sampling period.

According to the *Digital Control of Dynamic Systems* there are two versions of the discrete observer:

- *Prediction observer* - estimation of the state is based on system outputs from previous time step

$$
\bar{\mathbf{x}}(k) = \mathbf{A}_d\cdot\bar{\mathbf{x}}(k-1) + \mathbf{B}_d\cdot\mathbf{u}(k-1) + \mathbf{L}_{pd}\cdot\left[\mathbf{y}(k-1)-\mathbf{C}_d\cdot\bar{\mathbf{x}}(k-1)\right]
$$

- *Current observer*   - estimation of the state is based on system outputs at current time step

Its calculation consists of calculation of the prediction of the state estimate at first

$$
\bar{\mathbf{x}}(k) = \mathbf{A}_d\cdot\hat{\mathbf{x}}(k-1) + \mathbf{B}_d\cdot\mathbf{u}(k-1)
$$

and then calculation of the state estimate

$$
\hat{\mathbf{x}}(k) = \bar{\mathbf{x}}(k) + \mathbf{L}_{cd}\cdot\left[\mathbf{y}(k) - \mathbf{C}_d\cdot\bar{\mathbf{x}}(k)\right],
$$

where \$\mathbf{L}_{cd} = \mathbf{A}^{-1}_d\cdot\mathbf{L}_{pd}\$.

I was curious how will be the differences between outputs of the individual observers (continuous time domain observer, discrete predictor observer, discrete current observer). I have prepared a simulation in the Scilab/Xcos for that purposes. In that simulation all the three observers are estimating the state of three phase induction motor whose model runs in parallel.

I have encountered following behavior of the observers in relation to the value of the sampling period:

1. *black* - reality (comming from the model of the induction motor)
2. *green* - estimate offered by the continuous time observer
3. *red*   - estimate offered by the predictor observer
4. *blue*  - estimate offered by the current observer

Graphs:

1. \$T = 1\,\mu s\$

\$i_{s\alpha}\$:

[image]

\$i_{s\beta}\$:

[image]

\$\psi_{r\alpha}\$:

[image]

\$\psi_{r\beta}\$:

[image]

2. \$T = 10\,\mu s\$

\$i_{s\alpha}\$:

[image]

\$i_{s\beta}\$:

[image]

\$\psi_{r\alpha}\$:

[image]

\$\psi_{r\beta}\$:

[image]

3. \$T = 100\,\mu s\$

\$i_{s\alpha}\$:

[image]

\$i_{s\beta}\$:

[image]

\$\psi_{r\alpha}\$:

[image]

\$\psi_{r\beta}\$:

[image]

State estimate comming from the continuous time observer is in exact accordance with the reality (green curve lies over the black one). It is not surprising because the observer and the model use exactly the same state space description of the induction motor. With increasing sampling period I observe increase in state estimation error at both of the discrete observers in respect with the continuous observer (it is worthwhile to say that the state estimation error is less at the Current observer because it uses the freshest value of the system outputs for correction of the prediction of the state estimate). What I don´t understand is why there is so huge estimation error in respect with the continuous observer (especially for the components of the stator currents) for both the discrete observers for \$T = 10\,\mu s\$ and \$T = 100\,\mu s\$. Is it caused only by the discretization process (and probably too long sampling period in respect to the time constant which influence the stator current dynamic) or does it mean that there is some error in my simulation? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: One suggestion, when plotting different things that will probably be on top of each other try using different markers, such as 'x', '+', 'o' and so on, it improves the readability.

Comment: @Steve The Ad and Bd approximations you used fit best for small sampling period T, and you're likely seeing the consequences of increased T. Only way we can confirm if there's some error in your simulation is if we try to reproduce your results. If this question stays unanswered, I will do so during the weekend. I would expect the "prediction" and "current" approaches to have similar dynamics, your graphs match this expectation.

Comment: @Steve Have you attempted the exact zero-order hold discretization? Computing \$A_d = e^{AT}\$ instead of using approximations?

Comment: I agree with @VicenteCunha . Also, have you checked the poles of the observer after discretization ?  Are they still inside unit circle ? What about the plant ?

Comment: @VicenteCunha as far as your suggestion to compute \$A_d=e^{A_d}\$

Comment: Do you think to use following formula from the Digital Control of Dynamic Systems: \$\mathbf{A}_d = \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{A}\cdot T\cdot\mathbf{\Psi} = \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{A}\cdot T\cdot\Sigma^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{\mathbf{A}^k\cdot T^k}{(k+1)!}\$

Comment: and use some higher value of \$k\$ (for example \$k = 10\$)?

Comment: @AJN thank you for your reaction. The problem which I have with your suggestion is that the poles of the plant and also poles of the observer are speed dependent. So I can evaluate them only in some operating points specified by the mechanical speed. Do you have any idea what values of mechanical speed would be usefull for poles evaluation?

Comment: @Steve Only if you are too constrained in processing power... calculating the exponential can be simple if you find eigenvalues and eigenvectors to diagonalize the matrix. Do you have a specific hardware picked for your controller yet?

Comment: @VicenteCunha I have spent some time by integration of the matrix operations into my C code in the Scilab/Xcos simulation to have mathematical "tools" for implementing the more precise discretization methods for the \$\mathbf{A}_d\$ and \$\mathbf{B}_d\$ based on the \$\mathbf{\Psi}\$ matrix mentioned above. I have followed the recommendation from the Digital Control of Dynamic Systems and I have used 11 elements of the above mentioned series. Unfortunatelly the behavior is basically the same. Also the observer with more precise discretization has huge estimation error for longer \$T\$.

Comment: @VicenteCunha I have just encountered interesting behavior. Until this moment I have used one clock source (SampleCLK block) for generating the sampling period and different clock source (CLOCK_c block) for generating inputs for the CSCOPE blocks which I have been using for monitoring the simulation. The SampleCLK block used the sampling time T and the CLOCK_c block used 0.0001 s. In case I use only one clock source (CLOCK_c) with sampling time T the outputs of the discrete observers started to give estimates which follow the output of the continuous time observer.

Comment: @VicenteCunha do you have explanation for the behavior described above?

Comment: @VicenteCunha it seems to be a general problem signalizing my misunderstanding of how to simulate continuous time domain system along with discrete time domain systems. I have hit the problem again: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/521776/pid-controller-simulation-in-scilab-xcos. May I ask you for your opinion?

Comment: @Steve Unfortunately I have no experience with Scilab Xcos, I've always used Matlab Simulink during my study and research years. From your other question, seems like Xcos has some funny ideas on the behaviour of "scope clock". Perhaps exporting the signals to workspace and avoiding Xcos scopes is a solution?

Comment: @VicenteCunha I see. Let's say I will use Simulink instead. Please can you tell me what your approach would look like?