# PID controller simulation in Scilab/Xcos

Tags: simulation, control, control-system, pid-controller

I have been attempting to resolve following issue related to the simulation in Scilab/Xcos. I have been developing a control software and at the time being I have been developing a library of the building blocks. One of the building blocks is a PID controller. I have written the C code of the PID controller in velocity form and my idea was to verify its behavior via simulation in Scilab/Xcos with the CBLOCK usage. For that purpose I have developed following simulation in Scilab/Xcos

[image]

The internal details of the PID Controller super block:

[image]

the code inside the CBLOCK:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <scicos_block.h>
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *f;

// U(k-1)
double U1 = 0.0; 
// E(k-1)
double E1 = 0.0;
// E(k-2)
double E2 = 0.0;
// Ud(k-1)
double Ud1 = 0.0;
// Ud(k-2)
double Ud2 = 0.0;
// act(k-1)
double A1 = 0.0;
// act(k-2)
double A2 = 0.0;

void PID_controller(scicos_block *block,int flag)
{
  /* 
  int block->nevprt;
  int block->nz;
  double* block->z;
  int block->nx;
  double* block->x;
  double* block->xd;
  double* block->res;
  int block->nin;
  int *block->insz;
  double **block->inptr;
  int block->nout;
  int *block->outsz;
  double **block->outptr;
  int block->nevout;
  int block->nrpar;
  double *block->rpar;
  int block->nipar;
  int *block->ipar;
  int block->ng;
  double *block->g;
  int *block->jroot;
  char block->label[41];
  */
  if (flag == 4) { /* initialization */
   PID_controller_bloc_init(block,flag);
 
  } else if(flag == 1) { /* output computation*/
   set_block_error(PID_controller_bloc_outputs(block,flag));
  } else if(flag == 2) { /* computation of next discrte state*/ 
     set_block_error(PID_controller_bloc_states(block,flag));
  } else  if (flag == 5) { /* ending */
     set_block_error(PID_controller_bloc_ending(block,flag));
  }
}
 
int PID_controller_bloc_init(scicos_block *block,int flag)
{

f = fopen("PID.txt", "w");  
fprintf(f, "R           A2          A1        A       E2          E1           E           DUp         DUi         DUd         U1          U          SatU\n");
fprintf(f, "==============================================================================================================================================================================================================\n");

return 0;
}

int PID_controller_bloc_outputs(scicos_block *block,int flag)
{

// block parameters
double Kp;
double Ti;
double Td;
double N;
double Umin;
double Umax;
double T;

// reference value
double R;
// actual value
double A;
// control error
double E;
// control value
double U;
double SatU;

// increment of proportional part
double DUp;
// increment of integration part
double DUi;
// increment of derivative part
double DUd;
// derivative part
double Ud;
// increment of control value
double DU;


// reading in of the block inputs
R      = block->inptr[0][0];
A      = block->inptr[1][0];

// reading in of the block parameters
Kp   = block->rpar[0];
Ti   = block->rpar[1];
Td   = block->rpar[2];
N    = block->rpar[3];
Umin = block->rpar[4];
Umax = block->rpar[5];
T    = block->rpar[6]; 

// current control error
E = R - A;                                                

DUp = Kp*(E - E1);                                            // increment of proportional part 
DUi = (Kp*T)/(2*Ti)*(E + E1);                                         // increment of integration part
DUd = (Td)/(Td + N*T)*(Ud1 - Ud2) - (Kp*Td*N)/(Td + N*T)*(A - 2*A1 + A2); // increment of derivative part with filtering pole
Ud = Ud1 + DUd;                               // derivative part
DU = DUp + DUi + DUd;                                             // increment of control value
U  = U1 + DU;                                                 // control value

// saturation of the control value according to the limits of the actuator
if(U > Umax)
{
    SatU = Umax;
}
else if(U < Umin)
{
    SatU = Umin;
}
else
{
    SatU = U;
}

U1 = SatU;

// writing at the outputs
block->outptr[0][0] = SatU;

fprintf(f, "%f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f %f %f %f %f %f %f \n", R, A2, A1, A, E2, E1, E, DUp, DUi, DUd, U1, U, SatU);

// memory refresh
E2 = E1;
E1 = E;
A2 = A1;
A1 = A;
Ud2 = Ud1;
Ud1 = Ud;

return 0;
}

int PID_controller_bloc_states(scicos_block *block,int flag)
{

return 0;
}

int PID_controller_bloc_ending(scicos_block *block,int flag)
{

fclose(f);

return 0;
}
```

I have run the simulation with below given setup

[image]

and I have received following outcomes

[image]

The outcomes seemed strange to me. So I have decided to develop the whole simulation in C language in parallel. The C code of my simulation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// random noise in <-0.01; +0.01>
#define RANDOM_NOISE (0.02*((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX) - 0.01)


FILE *f;

typedef struct
{
    float T;
    float tau;
    float out1;
}FilterLP_t;

typedef struct
{
    float T;
    float Kp;
    float Ti;
    float Td;
    float N;
    float OutMin;
    float OutMax;
    float Ud1;
    float Ud2;
    float U1;
    float Err1;
    float Err2;
    float Act1;
    float Act2;
}PID_t;

void filter(float *in, float *out, FilterLP_t *instance);
void pid(float *ref, float *act, float *out, PID_t *instance);

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    f = fopen("PID_Sim.txt", "w");
    
    FilterLP_t sysModel;
    sysModel.T   = 0.01;
    sysModel.tau = 10.0;
    sysModel.out1= 0.0;
    
    PID_t controller;
    controller.T      = 0.01;
    controller.Kp     = 3.0;
    controller.Ti     = 0.125;
    controller.Td     = 2.0;
    controller.N      = 2.0;
    controller.OutMin = 0.0;
    controller.OutMax = 1.5;
    controller.Ud1    = 0.0;
    controller.Ud2    = 0.0;
    controller.U1     = 0.0;
    controller.Err1   = 0.0;
    controller.Err2   = 0.0;
    controller.Act1   = 0.0;
    controller.Act2   = 0.0;
    
    float ref            = 1.0;
    float sysIn;
    float sysOut         = 0.0;
    float sysOutMeasured = 0.0;
    
    fprintf(f, "r(k),   u(k),   y(k)\n");
    fprintf(f, "====================\n");
        
    uint16_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
    {
        pid(&ref, &sysOutMeasured, &sysIn, &controller);
        filter(&sysIn, &sysOut, &sysModel);
        sysOutMeasured = sysOut;
        fprintf(f, "%f, %f, %f \n", ref, sysIn, sysOut);
    }
    
    fclose(f);
    
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void filter(float *in, float *out, FilterLP_t *instance)
{
    float tmp;
    
    tmp = instance->out1 + (instance->T/(instance->T + instance->tau))*(*in - instance->out1);
    instance->out1 = tmp;
    *out = tmp;
}

void pid(float *ref, float *act, float *out, PID_t *instance)
{
    double Ki, Ad, Bd;
    double Err, DUp, DUi, DUd, Ud, DU, U, SatU;
    
    
    Ki = (instance->Kp*instance->T)/(2*instance->Ti);
    Ad = instance->Td/(instance->Td + instance->N*instance->T);
    Bd = (instance->Kp*instance->Td*instance->N)/(instance->Td + instance->N*instance->T);
       
    Err = *ref - *act;
    
    DUp = instance->Kp*(Err - instance->Err1);
    DUi = Ki*(Err + instance->Err1);
    DUd = Ad*(instance->Ud1 - instance->Ud2) - Bd*(*act - 2*instance->Act1 + instance->Act2);
    Ud  = instance->Ud1 + DUd;
    DU  = DUp + DUi + DUd;
    U   = instance->U1 + DU;
    
    if(U > instance->OutMax)
    {
        SatU = instance->OutMax;
    }
    else if(U < instance->OutMin)
    {
        SatU = instance->OutMin;
    }
    else
    {
        SatU = U;
    }
    
    instance->U1 = SatU;
    
    *out = SatU;
    
    instance->Err2 = instance->Err1;
    instance->Err1 = Err;
    instance->Act2 = instance->Act1;
    instance->Act1 = *act;
    instance->Ud2  = instance->Ud1;
    instance->Ud1  = Ud;
}
```

I have run the simulation with exactly the same PID controller settings and I have received these outcomes

[image]

There are obvious differences between what the Scilab/Xcos gives and what gives my simulation in C language. I trust more the C language simulation. So I would say that there is some problem in my simulation in the Scilab/Xcos. Unfortunatelly I don't know what is wrong. It seems that the control loop in the Scilab/Xcos has lower damping than in the C language simulation. Does anybody have any idea why this behavior occurs? Thanks for any ideas.

**UPDATE**:

Scilab/Xcos simulation outcomes in case one clock source is used for whole simulation

[image]

Comment: Without details about the PID blocks, themselves, noone can tell (both Xcos and C). It looks like the period for the Xcos is ~3.x times greater, maybe `pi`? Maybe the sampling? Maybe the PID in Xcos has different settings?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen thank you for your reaction. I have just attempted to append the missing details into the question.

Comment: The values for `Kp`, `Ti`, etc, are defined in the C code, but in the Xcos code all I can see is that they are read from `block->rpar[n]`. Can you verify that the values correspond? In rest, the code looks equivalent (I hope I didn't miss out on anything).

Comment: I am not familiar with Xcos. Does Xcos use fixed time step or variable time step for integration of the block diagrams ? CBLOCK code seems to be written for fixed step. Is it so ?

Comment: @AJN thank you for your reaction. Yes, you are correct. The code inside the CBLOCK suppose fixed time step. As far as the time step actually used I have been using the solver Sundials/CVODE-BDF-NEWTON. I have been looking for information about that solver in relation to the integration time step.

Comment: [This Scholarpedia article](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Sundials_equation_solvers) says: "*variable-order, variable-step linear multistep method families*". The variables `E1` and `E2` are global variables in the CBLOCK code. If the Xcos solver calls the CBLOCK code (causing E1 to be updated) and notices that it took too big a time step and *goes back in time* to repeat with a smaller step size, the information in E1 would correspond to the original big time step attempt right ? (I'm not familiar with Xcos and am speaking from my experience with Simulink)

Comment: @AJN based on following link: https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.0/en_US/CVode.html I would say that the Sundials/CVODE-BDF-NEWTON solver uses variable integration time step.

Comment: @AJN as far as your last comment. The code inside the CBLOCK suppose fixed sampling period. Correct me if I am wrong but I would say that the sampling period should be fix irrespective of the variability of the integration step.

Comment: I missed the `S\H` block.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen as far as the values of the PID parameters I have just verified that the expected values are passed into the internal variables of the CBLOCK. So the PID control algorithm uses correct values.

Comment: @Steve Well, about the only thing left that I can see is that you are using two clocks in Xcos. Have you tried using the same clock for the scope, too?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I have just replaced the clock for the scope by the clock signal used for timing of the rest of the simulation and the simulation outcomes are in accordance with the outcomes comming from the C language simulation! Do you have explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Sounds like aliasing. What values did they have? Try a separate schematic running a simple sine through your custom PID block with the same clock for both the controller and the scope, then with separate clocks, preferably as they were. Anyway you look at it, different sampling frequencies result in a stretching of the frequency domain.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen in the original simulation with two clock sources the sampling control clock was set to \$0.01\,\mathrm{s}\$ and the scope control clock was set to \$0.001\,\mathrm{s}\$. In the simulation with one clock source the clock was set to \$0.01\,\mathrm{s}\$. As far as I understand your comment you mean that in case I have a continuous time domain system and a discrete time domain system in one simulation I have to use one clock source otherwise the aliasing occurs. Is that correct?

Comment: Aliasing occurs when a signal is beyond the Nyquist limit. E.g. for a 10 Hz sampling, Nyquist is 5 Hz, so the signal period must be less than (but not equal to) 5 Hz. If the signal is 6 Hz, there's aliasing. Also, don't forget that the "continuous-time" blocks are internally solved with discrete values. But in this case you're oversampling by a factor of 10x, the waveforms should be smoother. Strange. I tried making your schematic, but it complained at compile about `uint32_t`, said it needed `u_int32_t`, but still it crashes. Maybe the scope clock acts as a displaying function? I don't know.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen as far as your compilation problem. Did you try to use int data type instead? What Scilab version do you use? I have been working with version 5.5.2.

Comment: @Steve Yes, but still it crashed. I use 6.1.0, Linux. Maybe the other settings are wrong? I used the `SUPER_f` in `User defined`, set it to two inputs, then I placed inside `CBLOCK` (not `CBLOCK_4`, not `c_block`). When I set it to two inputs it doesn't change to show two inputs, and if I change to `time dependent`, no additional clock input shows up. If I use the `PID_controller` as "simulation function", it compiles, but says `PID_controller is not an entry point`. Simulation fails with `unable to build block` and such. What settings have you used for it? Any external library?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen as far as the PID controller block building procedure. I have placed the CBLOCK into the canvas at first and then I have appended the IN's and OUT's blocks. At the end I have encapsulated all these stuff into the SUPERBLOCK. As far as the external library. I haven't been using any external library.